# In AWS Cognito, the user has been deleted for the associated refresh token

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito with iOS. These are the steps I am taking:

1. I register a new user
2. I confirm the new user via confirmation code from email

My next step is to save some custom values to dataset... however every time I attempt to synchronize I get an error stating "The user has been deleted for the associated refresh token".

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing a step? I believe I followed the documentation properly.

Comment: Have you deleted the user from AWS Cognito console?

Comment: @Karthick no, I would have caught that :P

Answer (score 0):

I need a few details... So when you say register, you mean pool.signUp? And when you say confirm you mean user.confirmSignUp?  And when you say save custom values to the dataset do you mean saving values to a dataset via cognito sync, to the identity ID datasets?

If so, then you need to make sure you call the methods getSession and credentials so that you are truly logged in before saving data to the identitId's or you will (a: put it in a unauth identityID (if you allow unauthorized users), b: get rejected because there is no identityId, or c: not have credentials to do the operation).

The error you are getting is not in the SDK and not in mobile hub so it must be from the restful API.  Is that the text of the exact error?